# How do you reuse the Statement in JDBC after reconnecting to the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My JDBC connection to the MySQL database expires after 10 seconds of inactivity. After I reconnect, I can't do any queries, it keeps on asking me if I wanna reconnect as if the connection is still closed.

I have:
 1. a global Statement called st,
 2. a global ResultSet called rs,
 
 3. a global connection called conn,
 
 4. a method setConnection that sets up the connection,
 
 5. a method checkConnection that checks if the connection is alive and if not it calls the setConnection method to establish a new one,
 
 6. a button that calls checkConnection and if the boolean returned is true, it executes a query

```
private Connection conn = null;
private Statement st=null;
private ResultSet rs=null;

    public void setConnection(){
             host="localhost";
             database="test";
             username="testtest";
             password="testtest";
             String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" +database+ "";
             try {
                 Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, username, password);
                 System.out.println("Succesfuly connected to the database!");

             } catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("Failed to connect to the database.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }  
        }

    private boolean checkConnection(){
            try {
                ResultSet cc = st.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
                return true;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        frame,
                        "The connection was closed, reconnect?",
                        "Database security measure",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                      setConnection();
                    } else if ( n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                        new LoginWindowB();
                    }
                return false;
            }
        }
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if(checkConnection()){
                        try {
                            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + selectedTable);
                            loadData(rs);

                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                }   
            });
```

How can I handle this reconnect matter and why do the query not work after setting up a new connection?

Comment: Your code snippets are not complete enough to analyze. You don't show your initialization or handling of the Statement object, which could be significant here. You have also not included the specifics of your problem (e.g. stack trace) which would help to further pinpoint the issues at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you initialize `st` in your example, but it smells like the culprit. When you create a new connection, you have to create a new statement as well.

All the `PreparedStatement` are attached to a client and will be closed with the connection.

It may be easier to use a *Connection Pool manager* library.

Comment: Actually from your answer, I figured the solution. The st was initialized only one time and when I would reconnect, it didn't initialize it again. I added the initialization of the st inside checkconnection just after the  call to the setConnection(); method and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I said... glad that you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you reuse the `Statement` in JDBC after reconnecting to the database?

You can't.

> I have:
>   1. a global `Statement` called `st`

Wrong already. You can't have global statements. Statements are coextensive with the connections they are created from. You should have a *local variable* `Statement. It cannot possibly be global.

> 2. a global `ResultSet` called `rs`

Wrong again. A `ResultSet` is coterminous with the `Statement` it is created from. It should be a local variable. It cannot possibly be global.

> 3. a global connection called conn

Wrong again. You should be using a connection *pool*, and have a *local variable `conn`.

> 4. a method `setConnection` that sets up the connection

Wrong again. It should be a method `getConnection()` that *returns* a new connection.

> 5. a method checkConnection that checks if the connection is alive and if not it calls the setConnection method to establish a new one

Wrong again. This method should not even exist. This is the job of the connection pool.

> 6. a button that calls checkConnection and if the boolean returned is true, it executes a query

Wrong again. It should be a button that:

1. gets a connection from `getConnection()`
2. creates a statement with `Connection.createStatement()` or `Connection.prepareStatement()`
3. Executes the statement, traverses the `ResultSet`, and populates whatever it has to populate with the result rows.